# How to make check boxes checked on a Grid view when one checkbox of a row is checked?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview. Which consisits of two checkbox item templates.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 

 <Columns>

   <asp:BoundField DataField="student_name" HeaderText="Student Name"            SortExpression="student_name" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
 </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="student_id" 
    HeaderText="Student ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        SortExpression="student_id" ReadOnly="True" >
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Practical Test">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="false" Checked="true" Id="CheckBoxTheory"  runat="server" />
     </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Theory Test">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="false" Checked="true" Id="CheckBoxPractical" runat="server"  />
  </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
```

When checking any one of the checkbox of a row of grid view ,i wants to make check the other checkbox automatically..and vice versa.. how is it possible?

Comment: Server side or client side? Would you use Javascript or prefer a postback to run it?

Comment: on server side. please help

Answer (score 0):

On server side you need to change the checkbox so it has `AutoPostBack="True"` and add a `OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxTheory_Checked"` so that the system can postback when you select it.

Then you can use something along the lines of:

```
Sub CheckBoxTheory_Checked (sender as object, e as eventargs)
    Dim CheckBoxTheory as CheckBox = sender
    Dim gvRow as GridviewRow = DirectCast(CheckBoxTheory.NamingContainer, GridviewRow)
    Dim CheckBoxPractical as CheckBox = gvRow.FindControl("CheckBoxPractical")
    If CheckBoxTheory.Checked = True Then
        CheckBoxPractical.Checked = True
    Else
        CheckBoxPractical.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This would get the `sender` as the checkbox, get the parent container (or `NamingContainer`), which would be a `GridviewRow` and then find the `CheckBoxPractical` control and then check if against the other checkbox value.

This is a long winded way of doing it but is the simplest at explaining the method.